# Como atualizar uma div com anúcio do adsense em x segundos, sem atualizar a página

Tags: php, javascript, html5, wordpress, google-adsense

Tenho um site com anúncios do adsense, queria um script ou javascript ou php para atualizar ele de x em x segundos, um loop. Na  base de 30 em 30 segundos.

Answer (score -1):

Olá!

Sem atualizar a página você precisará usar um pouco de ajax, e para fazer este reload de x em X segundo, você pode utilizar o setInterval, segue referências para você se basear:

[Docuemntação Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

[Documentação setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Com relação ao adsense, teria que ver a forma como você está inserindo ele na página atualmente, pelo que me recordo é o próprio Google que fornece o código de anúncio, então você precisará ler também na documentação dele:
[Documentação AdSense](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/libraries?hl=pt-br)